# How do you fix intellij strange string indentation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indentation, code-formatting, auto-indent

Intellij keeps on formatting my strings like this, its annoying...

How do I fix it so the lines all line up?

```
PreparedStatement p = s.prepare(
        "select distinct resource, uid, role " +
                "from role " +
                "where person_uuid=? " +
                "order by role, resource, uid");
```

I.E.:

```
PreparedStatement p = s.prepare(
        "select distinct resource, uid, role " +
        "from role " +
        "where person_uuid=? " +
        "order by role, resource, uid");
```

Comment: I'm a recent IntelliJ convert, and I was wondering the same thing...

Comment: I don't have an informed answer about IntelliJ, but Eclipse has a preference page with per-language formatting rules. Can you find such a page in the IntelliJ preferences?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can adjust the formatting in Project Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces. The option you are looking for should be either "Method call arguments" or "Binary Expressions"

Comment: Indeed. Binary Expressions -> Align When Multiline

Comment: Eclipse has much more fine grained support for adjustments here, which makes it hard to conform to eclipse code styles in this case.

Comment: Works fine as long as you are not combining a Kotlin Elvis operator with a long exception string :)